# parent has all of children group in many to many relation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, join, has-many-through

I'm not really sure on the correct terminology for this so I am unable to find any help.

Using Rails 4 I have a many to many relation between Film and Tag through film_tags. I want to scope films to only return films that contain a group of tags. For example Action and Comedy are both tags and I would like to search films that have both of these. Currently my system accidently does an 'or' search so that it returns all films that have Action or Comedy:

Film:

```
scope :includes_tags, ->(tags) {joins(:film_tag).merge(FilmTag.tags(tags))}
```

FilmTag:

```
scope :tags, ->(tags) {where(['film_tags.tag_id IN (?)',tags.map(&:id)])}
```

Is there away to filter by both these tags in such a way that I can continue to chain scopes after?

Comment: Your ``join`` is plural for ``film_tags`` (``joins(:film_tags)``), isn't it?

Comment: Oops yeah it is in my code, just a typo on here.

Comment: Did you have a look at my answer? Useful?

Comment: I'm just in the process of implementing it at the moment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice! Let me know if  it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group` and `having` statements to build your scope like this (untested):

```
class Film < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :includes_tags, ->(tags) do 
    joins(:film_tags).merge(FilmTag.tags(tags))
    .group("films.id")
    .having("count(film_tags.id) = ?", tags.size) 
  end
end
```

---

If `Tag` had an attribute called `name`, you could refactor your code like this for better performance and readability:

```
class FilmTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  # remove the .tags scope
end

class Film < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :film_tags 
  has_many :tags, through: :film_tags 

  scope :with_all_tag_names, ->(tag_names) do 
    joins(film_tags: :tags)
    .where(tags: { name: tag_names })
    .group("films.id")
    .having("count(tags.name) = ?", tag_names.size) 
  end
end
```